# Energy momentum tensor and 4-velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

A rope of mass per unit length $\mu$ has a static breaking strength $F$. What is the largest possible $F$ that does not violate the *weak energy condition*, i.e. $T^{00}$ should be positive to all observers?
I found a solution where $T^{0'0'}$ is given by
$$T^{0'0'}=T^{\mu\nu}U_\mu U_\nu$$
where $U^\mu$ is the four velocity of the observer. Can anyone help me derive the given equation? $T^{0'0'}$ is the $T^{00}$ measured by a moving observer with 4-velocity U

Notice, $T^{\mu\nu}$ has only two nonzero component, if you consider $F$ in the $z$-direction, then only $T^{00}$ and $T^{zz}$ are non-zero.

Comment: Can you clarify the expression for $T^{0'0'}$, the summation convention doesn't look correct, also the final solution should give a condition on $F$, then people can try to help you.

Comment: $T^{0'0'}$ is the $T^{00}$ measured by a moving observer with 4-velocity U

Comment: I mean as it is written the indices of the equation are not correct, please check that

Comment: It looks like it holds for a boost along the z axis, since $U=(\gamma, 0, 0, \gamma\beta)$ looks  like $\Lambda_{0\nu}$... do you know how to transform $T$ by the standard Lorentz method?

Comment: I don't completely understand the setup. Is the rope under tension with tension $F$?

Comment: @javier yes it is under tension F

Comment: @ohneval this equation is given in the problem book on relativity by lightman, price

Comment: @JEB does the equation hold for boost in arbitrary direction?

Comment: Then a different summation convention must be given other than Einstein's summation convention ... some more context will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to work it out using:

$$T'^{\sigma\lambda}=\Lambda^{\sigma}_{\mu}\Lambda^{\lambda}_{\nu}T^{\mu\nu}$$

for a boost in the $z$-direction with only $T^{00}$ and $T^{zz}$:

$${\bf T'}=\gamma^2\left[\begin{array}{cc}1 &-\beta\\-\beta &1\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{cc}T^{00} &0\\0 &T^{zz}\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc}1 &-\beta\\-\beta &1\end{array}\right]$$

$${\bf T'}=\gamma^2\left[\begin{array}{cc}1 &-\beta\\-\beta &1\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{cc}T^{00} &-T^{00}\beta\\-T^{zz}\beta &T^{zz}\end{array}\right]$$

$${\bf T'}=\gamma^2
\left[\begin{array}{cc}T^{00}+\beta^2T^{zz} &-\beta(T^{00}+T^{zz})\\-\beta(T^{00}+T^{zz}) &\beta^2T^{00}+T^{zz}\end{array}\right]$$

Now compare that with:

$$ T'^{00}=\gamma^2\left[\begin{array}{cc}1 &+\beta\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{cc}T^{00} &0\\0 &T^{zz}\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}1 \\+\beta \end{array}\right]$$

$$ T'^{00}=\gamma^2\left[\begin{array}{cc}1 &+\beta\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{c}T^{00} \\+\beta T^{zz} \end{array}\right]$$

$$ T'^{00}=\gamma^2[T^{00}+\beta^2T^{zz}] $$

So yes. It is correct.

Comment: can it be generalizes for any arbitrary boost given by $\vec{v}=v_x \hat{i}+v_y \hat{j}+v_z\hat{k}$ ?